# Moving view closer to camera

Tags: ios, core-animation

I try to move UIView closer to camera by changing `CATransform3DMakeTranslation`. I imported QuartzCore but nothing happens

My code is following

```
let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "pan:")
dummyView.addGestureRecognizer(pan)

func pan(gesture:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gesture.state {
    case .Changed: fallthrough
    case .Ended:
        let translation = gesture.translationInView(dummyView)
        var transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, 0, translation.x)
        dummyView.layer.transform = transform

    default: break
    }
}
```

what im I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a sublayer transform to add perspective to your layers.

```
    var initialTransform = self.layer.transform
    initialTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500 //adjust this value for your needs
    self.layer.sublayerTransform = initialTransform
```

(Assuming `self.layer` is the superlayer of `dummyView.layer`)